# Use different length of ticks in one ggplot graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to apply different length of ticks in one ggplot graph, like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfUBl.png)

I tried to use

> scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(seq(0,1, by = 0.1),seq(1,5,1)))

to customize the ticks but this only gives different step sizes.
Any suggestions?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTavw.png)

Sorry the images are attached as links.

Comment: Please provide reproducible data and code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are observing is the effect of a logged x scale.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)

"x,y
0.09838589987314314, 431.84212280818747
0.19646546437091444, 1072.2954863657576
0.29750771557320366, 1347.2844856323754
0.3955242765781446, 1546.716447763184
0.49672163253953483, 1501.5827721848123
0.5940891079858363, 1320.5680378691911
0.6990737071572558, 1178.7879191946129
0.7962694810692876, 1061.1374091606106
0.8923393306748771, 919.3252883525568
0.9838589987314309, 831.8421228081871
1.1025615087338325, 744.3696246416428
1.1863284538600922, 678.0025335022334
1.286887658830817, 599.5653043536236
1.3959707710478373, 554.3356223748249
1.4898579966508398, 509.09527301820117
1.6030497343115249, 454.80365357690516
1.6696092455367386, 403.50956730448706
1.7674609336378837, 376.37709180612046
1.886333052497789, 346.2310820721382
1.9968863894545188, 322.11747449829977
2.079798216336457, 291.9554636975797
2.31183906016707, 255.79838655910407
2.5078022414885948, 213.5875725048336
2.6764666574617317, 192.49816654443634
2.9033375196831206, 162.36282418827932
3.0238856986296256, 153.3328888592573
3.149439104611845, 144.3029535302353
3.3340199781197377, 132.26481765451013
3.500818628686328, 117.20248016534447
3.6759620972244393, 111.19674644976362
3.7975657368770896, 99.14260950730068
3.923192118001404, 96.14507633842254
4.086085223703413, 96.17174478298557
4.616479953856948, 78.13854256950458
5.089953102964006, 63.10820721381424
5.61198637258845, 57.13447563170894
6.038356194859665, 51.14474298286564
6.712049082852011, 42.15747716514443
6.990737071572554, 33.12754183612242
7.521857271241964, 36.194412960864156
8.093329248357565, 27.185812387492433
8.226106849449925, 27.19647976531769
8.498232760057107, 27.217814520968204
8.85108408255861, 24.22561504100281
9.446371423329051, 24.268284552303612" %>% 
  read_csv() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1600, 200)) + 
  labs(x = "Window mm", 
       y = element_blank()) -> p

p
```

Produces this:

[image: no log plot]

But if we log the x scale:

```
p + 
  scale_x_log10(breaks = c(seq(0.1, 0.3, 0.1), seq(0.4, 0.8, 0.2), 1:10), 
                labels = c(seq(0.1, 0.3, 0.1), seq(0.4, 0.8, 0.2), 1:10))
```

We get this:

[image: logged plot]

Now you will have to apply this to your data.